# Collapsible right sidebar with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to make a collapsible right sidebar. Here are the requirements:

- Sidebar has a dynamic width and is build with flexbox;
- It needs to be uncollapsed by default and then on click on a button it will collapse;
- Browser needs to remember its state on reload ;
- Transition between the two states should be smooth;
- BUT there should be no transition effect when the sidebar is collapsed on page reload.

I am open to a javascript/jquery solution but i started with both css and jquery.

Here's my work so far:

```
$(function(){
  var closesidebar = $('.closesidebar');
  var className = "closed";
  
  $(".sidebar").toggleClass(className, localStorage.getItem("aside") === "Y");
  
  if($('.sidebar').hasClass(className)){
       closesidebar.addClass('opensidebar');
  }
  
  closesidebar.on("click", function(){  
    $(this).toggleClass('opensidebar');            
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass(className);
    
    if ($('.sidebar').hasClass(className)) {
        localStorage.setItem("aside", "Y");
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem("aside");
    }   
        
  });
});
```

```
.section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.main {
  width: 400px;
  flex-grow: 4;
  padding:15px 50px;
}
.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 200px;
  background: #1c1820;
  color:white;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
  padding:15px;
}
.closed{
  transform: translateX(100%);
  position: absolute;
}
.closesidebar{
  width:100%;
}
.closesidebar:before {
  content: 'Close';
}
.opensidebar:before {
  content: 'Open';
}
```

```
<div class="section">
  <button class="closesidebar"></button>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <h2>Sidebar</h2>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in augue nec enim facilisis pharetra. In cursus non dui eu convallis. Curabitur faucibus metus a orci placerat, vitae scelerisque augue facilisis. Etiam sagittis molestie ligula in congue. Phasellus euismod ex a risus tincidunt suscipit. Vivamus eu pharetra velit. Nam dignissim ante quis ullamcorper finibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed metus vel ipsum facilisis congue. Proin elementum tincidunt turpis in ornare.
   
  </div>
  <div class="main">
   <h2>Main content</h2>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in augue nec enim facilisis pharetra. In cursus non dui eu convallis. Curabitur faucibus metus a orci placerat, vitae scelerisque augue facilisis. Etiam sagittis molestie ligula in congue. Phasellus euismod ex a risus tincidunt suscipit. Vivamus eu pharetra velit. Nam dignissim ante quis ullamcorper finibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed metus vel ipsum facilisis congue. Proin elementum tincidunt turpis in ornare.
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus sed ornare elit. Phasellus nec facilisis augue. Phasellus ullamcorper cursus efficitur. Nulla facilisi. Sed vitae sagittis enim. Nam quis velit vel diam malesuada dignissim. Proin ac porta nulla. Aliquam venenatis vel dui et feugiat. Vestibulum eget convallis lacus, id luctus ante. Proin egestas ipsum massa. Ut aliquam est nisi, ac pulvinar nibh convallis vel. Nulla mi velit, luctus quis hendrerit ut, egestas ut augue. Fusce risus risus, pharetra facilisis porta nec, elementum vel ante. Curabitur in velit tortor. Etiam eu mi tempus neque lacinia malesuada at dictum lacus. 
  </div>
</div>
```

see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cd5t2px8/

Most of the requirements are met but some aren't and my problem lies with them:

- The transition between the two states isn't smooth because of the absolute positioning (but i needed it so the main content would resize);
- When the sidebar is collapsed, there is a transition effect on page reload from uncollapsed to collapsed state.

Comment: On mobile the effect is pretty disturbing at best. The main text jumps down to make room for some odd sidebar. Is that the desired?

Comment: I coded the flexbox in the jsfiddle pretty quickly and it's not mobile-friendly i'm sorry, maybe look at it on desktop instead for now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you are looking for, and I built two ways to achieve the same effect.

Built with Flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/yswqht8v/

Built with position absolute: https://jsfiddle.net/xn523kgr/

They all have the exact same HTML and Javascript

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var closesidebar = $('.closesidebar');
  var className = "closed";
  
  $(".sidebar").toggleClass(className, localStorage.getItem("aside") === "Y");
  
  if($('.sidebar').hasClass(className)){
       closesidebar.addClass('opensidebar');
  }
  
  closesidebar.on("click", function(){  
    $(this).toggleClass('opensidebar');            
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass(className);
    
    if ($('.sidebar').hasClass(className)) {
        localStorage.setItem("aside", "Y");
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem("aside");
    }   
        
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <button class="closesidebar"></button>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <h2>Sidebar</h2>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in augue nec enim facilisis pharetra. In cursus non dui eu convallis. Curabitur faucibus metus a orci placerat, vitae scelerisque augue facilisis. Etiam sagittis molestie ligula in congue. Phasellus euismod ex a risus tincidunt suscipit. Vivamus eu pharetra velit. Nam dignissim ante quis ullamcorper finibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed metus vel ipsum facilisis congue. Proin elementum tincidunt turpis in ornare.
   
  </div>
  <div class="main">
   <h2>Main content</h2>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc in augue nec enim facilisis pharetra. In cursus non dui eu convallis. Curabitur faucibus metus a orci placerat, vitae scelerisque augue facilisis. Etiam sagittis molestie ligula in congue. Phasellus euismod ex a risus tincidunt suscipit. Vivamus eu pharetra velit. Nam dignissim ante quis ullamcorper finibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed metus vel ipsum facilisis congue. Proin elementum tincidunt turpis in ornare.
     Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus sed ornare elit. Phasellus nec facilisis augue. Phasellus ullamcorper cursus efficitur. Nulla facilisi. Sed vitae sagittis enim. Nam quis velit vel diam malesuada dignissim. Proin ac porta nulla. Aliquam venenatis vel dui et feugiat. Vestibulum eget convallis lacus, id luctus ante. Proin egestas ipsum massa. Ut aliquam est nisi, ac pulvinar nibh convallis vel. Nulla mi velit, luctus quis hendrerit ut, egestas ut augue. Fusce risus risus, pharetra facilisis porta nec, elementum vel ante. Curabitur in velit tortor. Etiam eu mi tempus neque lacinia malesuada at dictum lacus. 
  </div>
</div>
```

The only difference is their CSS, you can pick and choose as needed.

Flexbox CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.main {
  flex: 4 2 auto;
  width: 0px;
  padding:15px 50px;
}
.sidebar {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 0px;
  background: #1c1820;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
}
.closed .main{
  width: 100%;
}
.closed .sidebar{
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.closesidebar{
  width:100%;
}
.closesidebar:before {
  content: 'Close';
}
.opensidebar:before {
  content: 'Open';
}
```

Position absolute CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  padding:15px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  background: #1c1820;
  color:white;
  padding:15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.closed .main{
  width: 100%;
} 
.closed .sidebar{
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.closesidebar{
  width:100%;
}
.closesidebar:before {
  content: 'Close';
}
.opensidebar:before {
  content: 'Open';
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i used your flexbox solution since it was part of my requirements, it works fine!